# React Native - Call Async Function From Another Component To Store and Get Data

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to call an async function to store and get data that I fetch from an API. The user is supposed to get a token on the login screen, and the token will be shown on the home screen. But the token is not shown in the console when the user presses the button on the home screen
link.js

```
export const SET_USER_AUTH = async ({accessToken, tokenType, expiresAt}) => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@access_token', accessToken);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@token_type', tokenType);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@expires_at', expiresAt);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@user_auth', tokenType + " " + accessToken);
        console.log("Done SET_USER_AUTH");
    } catch(e) {
    // read error
    }
};

export const GET_USER_AUTH = async () => {
    try {
        const accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@access_token');
        const tokenType = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token_type');
        const expiresAt = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@expires_at');
        const userVer = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_auth');
        console.log("Done GET_USER_AUTH");
    } catch(e) {
    // read error
    }
};
```

Home.js

```
return (
        <Button onPress={() => console.log(GET_USER_AUTH.userVer)}/>
    );
```

Comment: You can't do that, GET_USER_AUTH.userVer will show undefined

Comment: @luongvy is there no way for me to create the async function in another component instead of in the login screen?